# Scala & Spark: Recycling SQL statements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I spent quite some time to code multiple SQL queries that were formerly used to fetch the data for various `R` scripts. This is how it worked

```
sqlContent = readSQLFile("file1.sql")
sqlContent = setSQLVariables(sqlContent, variables)
results = executeSQL(sqlContent)
```

The clue is, that for some queries a result from a prior query is required - why creating `VIEW`s in the database itself does not solve this problem. With `Spark 2.0` I already figured out a way to do just that through

```
// create a dataframe using a jdbc connection to the database
val tableDf = spark.read.jdbc(...)
var tempTableName = "TEMP_TABLE" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString.replace("-", "").toUpperCase
var sqlQuery = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/sql/" + sqlFileName)).mkString
sqlQuery = setSQLVariables(sqlQuery, sqlVariables)
sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replace("OLD_TABLE_NAME",tempTableName)
tableDf.createOrReplaceTempView(tempTableName) 
var data = spark.sql(sqlQuery)
```

But this is in my humble opinion very fiddly. Also, more complex queries, e.g. queries that incooporate subquery factoring currently don't work. Is there a more robust way like re-implementing the SQL code into `Spark.SQL` code using `filter($"")`, `.select($"")`, etc.

**The overall goal** is to get multiple `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`s, each representing the results of one former SQL query (which always a few `JOIN`s, `WITH`s, etc.). So `n` queries leading to `n` `DataFrame`s.

Is there a better option than the provided two?

Setup: Hadoop `v.2.7.3`, Spark `2.0.0`, Intelli J IDEA `2016.2`, Scala `2.11.8`, Testcluster on Win7 Workstation

Comment: I didn't fully get that. You have multiple queries in single sql file and you want each query to be registered as TempView in the end? Or multiple sql files, each with one query and each query registering one TempView? I don't see the problem in the question.

Comment: The latter, thanks ! I added few infos to make that clear.

Comment: Ok, so you want n DataFrames from n sql Files. It's solved already in the code that you added. What is "fiddly" in your solution, why do you need "better" solution - what should the answer optimize?

Comment: Thanks! My code doesn't solve the problem - at least how I understand it. `sql()` can only be used along with registered temp views (`df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")` needs to be executed prior to `val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")`). This makes it impossible (to my probably limited understanding) to use it in scenarios, where more than one table/view is needed to generate the data (e.g. using a combination of `FROM` and `JOIN`s). What would solve my problem (I got to this point through our discussion) is a "take this SQL, run it against the database and return a DataFrame"

Comment: Another option would be if it's possible to specify the connection string (like for `spark.read.jdbc()`) when using `spark.sql()`

Answer (score 1):

It's not especially clear what your requirement is, but I think you're saying you have queries something like:

```
SELECT * FROM people LEFT OUTER JOIN places ON ...
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM people LEFT OUTER JOIN places ON ...) WHERE age>20
```

and you would want to declare and execute this efficiently as

```
SELECT * FROM people LEFT OUTER JOIN places ON ...
SELECT * FROM <cachedresult> WHERE age>20
```

To achieve that I would enhance the input file so each sql statement has an associated table name into which the result will be stored.

e.g.

```
PEOPLEPLACES\tSELECT * FROM people LEFT OUTER JOIN places ON ...
ADULTS=SELECT * FROM PEOPLEPLACES WHERE age>18
```

Then execute in a loop like

```
parseSqlFile().foreach({case (name, query) => {
    val data: DataFrame = execute(query)
    data.createOrReplaceTempView(name)
}
```

Make sure you declare the queries in order so all required tables have been created. Other do a little more parsing and sort by dependencies.

In an RDMS I'd call these tables Materialised Views. i.e. a transform on other data, like a view, but with the result cached for later reuse.