# Scala & Spark: Querying native SQL without a registered tempview

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to execute an `SQL` statement (including `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WITH` and different types of `JOIN`s) without the need for registering a temp view priorly in Spark using Scala? The goal is to get a `DataFrame` without any detours from SQL code.

An example how it works (using an existing `DataFrame` and registering a tempview) is provided by [the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection):

```
// df is an existing DataFrame
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
sqlDF.show()
```

The problem with an existing `DataFrame` is, that only sub quantities of the underlying `DataFrame`, used for generating the tempview, can be selected. This becomes very impractical if the SQL statements use data from many different tables or Views. Something like

```
// SQL is directly executed on database 
val dfView = spark.sql(connectionProperties,
                       "SELECT * 
                        FROM DATABASE_USER.V_VIEW_IN_DATABASE v1
                        JOIN DATABASE_USER.V_VIEW2_IN_DATABASE v2
                        ON v1.key = v2.key")
dfView.show()
```

with automatic type inference would solve my problem. I'm chasing one potential path pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663184/scala-spark-recycling-sql-statements).

Setup: Hadoop `v.2.7.3`, Spark `2.0.0`, Intelli J IDEA `2016.2`, Scala `2.11.8`, Testcluster on Win7 Workstation, Oracle 12c database

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
         .options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://<server>:<port>/<db>?user=<user>&password=<password>", "dbtable" -> "<dbtable>"))
         .load()
val ans = new SQLTransformer()
    .setStatement("SELECT value + id AS points FROM __THIS__")
    .transform(df)
ans.show()

+------+
|points|
+------+
| 101.0|
| 202.0|
+------+
```

If you want some sugar coating:

```
object ImprovedDataFrameContext {
    import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer

    implicit class ImprovedDataFrame(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) {
        def T(query: String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
            new SQLTransformer().setStatement(query).transform(df)
        }
    }
}
import ImprovedDataFrameContext._

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
         .options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://<server>:<port>/<db>?user=<user>&password=<password>", "dbtable" -> "<dbtable>"))
         .load()
         .T("<sql_query>")
         .show()

+------+
|points|
+------+
| 101.0|
| 202.0|
+------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I don't get how `Seq((1.0,100.0),(2.0,200.0))` can be replaced by something that queries data directly from the database ?

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that. What I don't understand is how to replace the sample dataframe code by some SQL that queries data from a database (e.g. jdbc), e.g. like `"SELECT * FROM DATABASE_USER.V_VIEW_IN_DATABASE"`. In other words, how do I create a `DataFrame` from SQL?

Comment: I've edited answer reading from postgres db (you will need to put the jdbc drivers in your spark classpath and set the proper connection options though).

Comment: Thanks again! One problem is left: The data used to create `DataFrame` is contained by multiple views tables - so I have to do some joining in my `SQL`. So `"dbtable" -> "<dbtable>"` in combination with `FROM __THIS__` will not work...

Comment: You can use something like: "dbtable" -> "(SELECT ... FROM ... [JOIN|ON|WHERE]) AS new_table" esentially: "dbtable" -> "(<subquery>) AS <table_name>", it should work but I'm not sure if the fact that the view are materialised or not will affect it somehow.